# How to detect cracked JS validation?

Tags: javascript, security, validation

I have a website with a quiz on it. The users cannot gain anything directly from doing well on that quiz, but they can share their result on Facebook and Twitter.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to check if the answer is correct or not. After each question, the user should be able to restart or continue if they got it wrong, or it will automatically continue if the user got it right.

If the check is done server side, the user have to wait for a second after submitting the answer before either the next question pops up or the two alternatives pop up. However, if I do it on the client side, there will be no delay and the users will be more happy.

So there isn't extremely much to gain on cheating, but certainly people will do this to show it off on Facebook and Twitter.

So, is there any way to do spot checks or any other method of DETECTING users cheating on the client side? Or do I simply have to decide where I want to do the validation?

Comment: If everything is based on what happens at the client, there's nothing you can do to prevent cheating.  Users are in complete control of their browser.

Comment: Is it that bad to wait a second for the response of the server?

Comment: @Pointy Exactly. That's why I'm considering server-side validation, so the users send their answer instead of validating it themselves. The question is just if there are any clever methods of doing spot checks. Myself I've thought about providing the client with a false solution to catch any cheaters, but it it's not very good, because then I'd have to make the client wait for the server to validate the answer, and a hacker would be aware of that and NOT cheat when this happens..

Comment: Instead of sending the answer back to the server for validation each time, why not save the answers in a client side object/array and send it to the server at the end?  EDIT I see you want to validate each question after it's answered, nevermind my comment.

Comment: @BenFelda Because if the answer is correct, the user should be presented with the next question. If it isn't correct, the user should be presented with two options, 1. Start over again, 2. Continue... So the client needs to know if the answer was correct or not.

Comment: Ok as @Syjin said server side validation is the only option. And there is one more option going the really really hard way of making the user difficult to crack the client side validation. Make the answer generate something like a hash that you would verify to see if that was the correct answer and every answer and question needs a different validation.....so I was just telling how difficult it would be to make the user difficult to crack client side validation, ...so I suggest do a simple post without a lot of data and get it validated :)

Comment: I think your best answer is server side validation if you are truly worried about the answers being tracked down client side.  Just make the server call really lean with a loader for the user.  As @theshadowmonkey points out, there are ways to make it difficult for the client, but not impossible.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts consider that the user can look at the code and figure out how to do the Facebook thing and then *completely bypass everything else*. If there's no secure component to the process, then, well, there's no secure component.

Comment: Even using use anonymous functions and scoping tricks won't be able to prevent a user bypassing everything unless you have some kind of server-side verification.

Comment: @Student of Hogwarts: you actually shouldn't delete your question :-( It's interesting and your solution could help someone. So could you un-delete it and put your solution as an answer please?

Comment: @zerkms You really think so? I thought this was uninteresting as almost no one did read it... But I'll un-delete it if you want to! :) I'll add an answer when I have finished my solution and tested it out.

Comment: @zerkms Seems like I have to re-create it. I can leave a comment here when I've made the answer if you're interested.

Comment: @Student of Hogwarts: I'm sure you can un-delete it. But anyway, i think it's a really interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent cheating if you do validation on the client side.  You can make it a little harder, but at the end of the day you do not control the user's browser, and your code must be executable.  Unless you take extra steps, it would easy to cheat simply by viewing the page source and looking at the code for the correct answer.  If you care about cheating, do all the validation on the server side.  Use AJAX to create a seamless user experience during the validation.  A couple seconds of waiting for an AJAX request is not bad, and will not create a poor user experience.

If you are dead set on client side validation, one trick that will make it a pain in the behind for an attacker is to obfuscate the JavaScript routine.  If you wrap an obfuscated code generator into a JS eval function call, the attacker will have to de-obfuscate it before they could determine the "correct" answer to the question.  This is easily done using [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey), but it would thwart the script kiddies and the lazies.  Your idea of using a wrong answer here and there may be good as well, when paired with the obfuscation.

At the end of the day though, I wouldn't do any validation client side at all.  Use the AJAX/server side combo to create a good experience for your users that is also fair.